# Can we sum data without sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I want related contracts with the rates and their difference as margin

I would like to do this sum in SQL Server without self joining the table in a sub query.

My Schema is set up as follows:

**Contracts**

```
ContractId  relatedContractId   Discriminator
-----------------------------------------------------
8041        8040                VendorContract
8040        8041                CustomerContract
8042        NULL                CustomerContract
8043        8044                CustomerContract
8044        8043                VendorContract
```

**Rates**

```
RateId  RatePerUnit ContractId
---------------------------------
8052    120.00      8041
8053    123.00      8041
8050    121.00      8040
8051    127.00      8040
8052    120.00      8042  
8053    137.00      8042
8054    102.00      8043
8055    100.00      8044
```

Expected Output is

```
CContract     VContract    Marging
------------------------------------
8040          8041         5.00 
8042          Null         257.00
8043          8044         2.00
```

I have achieved the correct result with the query below, which uses a sub query, but I need to do this without using a sub query.

```
SELECT  cts.ContractId,
        cts.RelatedContractId,
        (ISNULL(SUM(r.RatePerUnit),0) - ISNULL(vr.VendorContractRate,0)) AS Margin
FROM    Contracts cts
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Contracts vcts 
            ON cts.RelatedContractId = vcts.ContractId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Rates r 
            ON cts.ContractId = r.ContractId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  c.ContractId, 
                    ISNULL(SUM(r.RatePerUnit),0) VendorContractRate 
            FROM    Contracts c
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Rates r 
                        ON r.ContractId = c.contractId
            WHERE c.Discriminator = 'VendorContract' 
            GROUP BY c.ContractId
        ) vr 
            ON cts.RelatedContractId = vr.ContractId           
WHERE   cts.Discriminator = 'CustomerContract'
GROUP BY cts.ContractId, cts.RelatedContractId, vr.VendorContractRate;
```

I have tried to rewrite this query without using a sub query as follows:

```
SELECT  vc.ContractId, 
        SUM(r.RatePerUnit), 
        SUM(vr.RatePerUnit) 
FROM    Contracts c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Contracts vc 
            ON c.RelatedContractId = vc.ContractId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Rates r 
            ON r.ContractId= c.ContractId
        INNER JOIN Rates vr 
            ON vr.ContractId = vc.ContractId
WHERE   c.Discriminator = 'CustomerContract' 
AND     c.ContractStatus = 0
GROUP BY vc.ContractId;
```

Unfortunately this is duplicating my results, so it is not correct. For multiple rates, it multiplies the rates by the number of rates that exist. So I get the result:

```
CContract     VContract    Marging
------------------------------------
8040          8041         10.00       ---- in this case 496-486(248-243)
8042          Null         514.00      
8043          8044         2.00
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a subquery?

Comment: performance issue. please help me out without sub query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a simple way of doing this without a subquery of some sort, but there is also no reason to try and avoid a sub query. You have cited performance reasons for wanting to avoid a subquery, but this is not a valid reason, SQL is a declarative language, i.e. you tell the optimiser what you want rather than how to get it, so just because you have used a subquery does not mean that you are necessarility changing the plan.

Although there is no need to remove the subquery to improve performance, that is not to say that the performance of your query cannot still be improved. This can be done by removing unnecessary joins. The following should perform better:

```
WITH SummedRates AS
(   SELECT  ContractID, RatePerUnit  = SUM(RatePerUnit)
    FROM    Rates
    GROUP BY ContractID
)
SELECT  c.ContractID, 
        c.RelatedContractID,
        Margin = ISNULL(r.RatePerUnit, 0) - ISNULL(r2.RatePerUnit, 0)
FROM    Contracts AS c
        LEFT JOIN SummedRates AS r
            ON r.ContractId = c.ContractId
        LEFT JOIN SummedRates AS r2
            ON r2.ContractId = c.RelatedContractId
WHERE   c.Discriminator = 'CustomerContract'
```

**FULL WORKING DEMO**

```
DECLARE @Contracts TABLE (ContractId INT, relatedContractId INT, Discriminator VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @Contracts (ContractId, relatedContractId, Discriminator)
VALUES
    (8041, 8040, 'VendorContract'),
    (8040, 8041, 'CustomerContract'),
    (8042, NULL, 'CustomerContract'),
    (8043, 8044, 'CustomerContract'),
    (8044, 8043, 'VendorContract');

DECLARE @Rates TABLE (RateId INT, RatePerUnit DECIMAL(5, 2), ContractId INT);
INSERT @Rates (RateId, RatePerUnit, ContractId)
VALUES
    (8052, 120.00, 8041),
    (8053, 123.00, 8041),
    (8050, 121.00, 8040),
    (8051, 127.00, 8040),
    (8052, 120.00, 8042),
    (8053, 137.00, 8042),
    (8054, 102.00, 8043),
    (8055, 100.00, 8044);

WITH SummedRates AS
(   SELECT  ContractID, RatePerUnit  = SUM(RatePerUnit)
    FROM    @Rates
    GROUP BY ContractID
)
SELECT  c.ContractID, 
        c.RelatedContractID,
        Margin = ISNULL(r.RatePerUnit, 0) - ISNULL(r2.RatePerUnit, 0)
FROM    @Contracts AS c
        LEFT JOIN SummedRates AS r
            ON r.ContractId = c.ContractId
        LEFT JOIN SummedRates AS r2
            ON r2.ContractId = c.RelatedContractId
WHERE   c.Discriminator = 'CustomerContract';
```